# How can I output a plot in Shiny App that changes based on your inputs using R?

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently creating a tool in R to publish in ShinyApps that reports different values based on the function you select. One of the inputs into all functions is the interest rate.

My goal is to output a plot that shows the change in the value reported for a range of interest values, to show how the value of that product will change.

E.g. if I select product A for $1000, the function is 1000*(1+i)^-1. At 0% interest, it would be 1000, at 5% it would be 952.38 and at 15% it would be 869.56. I then want it to output a plot like this [Initial Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipN1W.png). If I then where to change the $1000 to $1, I would then want the plot to automatically update to [Updated Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x31tU.png) in my ShinyApp.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Page 1 of the shiny written tutorial creates a page very much like this - a slider for input and a plot for output.  [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/) - you should be easily able to adapt it to your needs.  Instead of a slider you will want a numeric input field.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen thanks for the reply. In my question, I think it is different, as for each price and interest chosen, the data for y changes. I was wondering how to incorporate this as in that example, the dataset is fixed.

Comment: You can have one selector for function and another for the interest rate (and more for any other settings)

Comment: example here: [link] (https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#conditional-ui) - includes how to have the settings for different models appear and disappear depending on the model chosen, and an example of a `switch` statement to select the appropriate code for that model.